# Laravel- Authorize.net not working in production mode

Tags: php, laravel-5, authorize.net

I am doing a transaction using visa credit card and it works fine on `Authorize.net`'s virtual terminal and in sandbox mode but when I change the keys and mode according to production, I am getting the following response

```
CreateTransactionResponse {#495 ▼
  -transactionResponse: TransactionResponseType {#545 ▼
    -responseCode: "2"
    -rawResponseCode: null
    -authCode: ""
    -avsResultCode: "P"
    -cvvResultCode: ""
    -cavvResultCode: ""
    -transId: "20188585160"
    -refTransID: ""
    -transHash: "E695B1BC8D328144E3C47D17A53B94E8"
    -testRequest: "0"
    -accountNumber: "XXXXXXXXX"
    -accountType: "Visa"
    -splitTenderId: null
    -prePaidCard: null
    -messages: null
    -errors: array:1 [▼
      0 => ErrorAType {#516 ▼
        -errorCode: "2"
        -errorText: "This transaction has been declined."
      }
    ]
    -splitTenderPayments: null
    -userFields: null
    -shipTo: null
    -secureAcceptance: null
  }
  -profileResponse: null
  -refId: "ref1474354204"
  -messages: MessagesType {#512 ▼
    -resultCode: "Ok"
    -message: array:1 [▼
      0 => MessageAType {#527 ▼
        -code: "I00001"
        -text: "Successful."
      }
    ]
  }
  -sessionToken: null
}
```

I don't understand the problem as it is giving me an error `Transaction has been declined` but in `messages`, result is ok and successful

Comment: The response indicates the customer's issuing bank declined the transaction.

Comment: Could you confirm if you're working in the sandbox or production?